# How can I change this sentence to avoid passive voice?

Tags: passive-voice

I have a press release that I've been asked to edit to remove passive voice. Having done some research via the Internet, I'm not entirely sure how to best change this sentence:

> **"We have gained many new responsibilities by being incorporated."**

Any support would be much appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: There is no passive voice in the sentence you quote. Find employment with more literate employers.

Comment: _Being incorporated_ can be parsed as passive, but the sentence itself is active voice.

Comment: @KarlG I s'pose the *can* was a considered word there. Because in this case, there need be no passive at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use "incorporation" instead?

Something like "Incorporation has afforded us many exciting new responsibilities and possibilities"?

Comment: You could mark my answer as correct? :-) Perhaps invert responsibilities and possibilities?

Comment: Sorry, got sidetracked — upvoted and marked!

Answer (score 0):

"Being incorporated," since it refers to the act of incorporation, can be parsed as passive here. You can rewrite it as,

> "We have gained many new responsibilities by incorporating."

Or even better:

> "Incorporating gives us many new responsibilities."

Comment: Neither gives the specific meaning of "being/ getting incorporated".

Comment: Much appreciate the examples!